# SQL Server Query: Daily Data Snapshot Comparison (Counting Delta Occurrences)

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am working towards counting customer subscription ("package") changes.  To do this, I am selecting all data from my package table once, every day.  I am calling the daily query results "snapshots" (approx 500k rows).  I then load the snapshot data into a new table.  After 10 days I have a total of 5 million rows in the snapshots table (500k rows * 10 days).  The majority of customers do not changes packages (65%).  I need to report which customers, of the remaining 35%, are switching packages, when they are switching packages, what package changes they are making (from "package X" to "package y") and which customers are changing packages most frequently.

The query I have written uses a `self-join`. I am identifying the changes but my results contain duplicate rows.

This is my query:

```
select *
 from UserPackageDump UPD1, UserPackageDump UPD2
 where UPD1.user_id = UPD2.user_id
 and UPD1.package_id <> UPD2.package_id
```

How can I change this query to yield only distinct results?

Comment: Looking at your query, i think using a DISTINCT should solve your problem. select distinct * from UserPackageDump

Comment: You should have a look at Change Data Capture rather than pulling all the records looking for the changes, it will make this a lot easier I would think.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT *
FROM 
  UserPackageDump UPD1 
JOIN UserPackageDump UPD2
  ON UPD1.user_id = UPD2.user_id
WHERE 
  UPD1.package_id <> UPD2.package_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You have many options for doing this, and I'm not sure your approach is the right one to take. Firstly to answer your specific question, you could perform a DISTINCT as per @sqlab's answer. Or you could include the date in the join, ensuring that UDP1 only matches a record in UDP2 that is one day different.

However, to come back to the approach, there should be no need to take a full copy of all the data. You have lots of other options for more efficient data storage, some of which being:

- Put a "LastUpdated" datetime2 field in the database, to be populated each time the row is changed.  Copy only those rows that have a LastUpdated more recent than the last time the copy was made. Assuming the only change possible to the table is to change the `package_id` then you will now only have rows in the table for users that have changed.
- Create a UserPackageHistory table into which rows are written each time a user subscribes to a package, at the same time that UserPackage is updated. This then leaves you with much the same result as the first bullet, but in advance of running the copy job.

Then, with any one of these sets of data, to satisfy the reporting requirements you could populate a cube. Your source would be a set of rows containing user_id, old_package_id, new_package_id and date. You would create a measure group containing these measures:

- Distinct count of user_id
- Count of switches (basically just the row count of the source data)

This measure group could then be related to the following dimensions:

- Date, so you can see when the switches are taking place
- User, so you can drill down on who is switching
- Switch Type, which is a dimension built from the selecting the old_package_id and new_package_id from your source data. This gives you the ability to see the popularity of particular shifts.